# Reading and Writng from a .csv file combo box

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have 10 .csv files which are monthly weather logs  which have 8 columns 
dd/mm/yy,Current time,temp,humidity,dpoint,wind speed,wind gust,wind bearing.

The files should be put into a combo box and be opened produce the output for the monthly average and display as

The .csv files are in this order

Date in the form dd/mm/yy
Current time
Current temperature
Current humidity
Current dewpoint
Current wind speed
Current wind gust
Current wind bearing

10/04/2012,00:00,6.439582,79.71528,3.138889,8.868753,33,264.8125
11/04/2012,00:00,7.853473,76.41666,3.701389,7.065973,33,277.4722
12/04/2012,00:00,7.622221,64.99306,0.9236111,6.268749,33,214.9861
13/04/2012,00:00,7.24236,66.82639,1.319444,6.898612,33,136.8472
14/04/2012,00:00,6.952778,55.40278,-1.548611,10.11389,33,109.5764
15/04/2012,00:00,6.285417,56.97222,-2.243056,6.869443,33,137.4861
16/04/2012,00:00,7.205556,67.625,1.3125,8.19236,33,149.9514

I need to output these values for a selected month into a listbox and output like this

Month:  Apr 2012
Temperature Avg:  3.45
Temperature Max: 54.34
Temperature Min: 3.4
Humidity: 34.5
Wind Speed:3.45
Wind Gust:54.34
Wind Direction: 53.56

Here is my code. I have gotten so far as adding the filenames into the combo box but I am not sure how to open and output them in Visual Basic.

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports System

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub cmb1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmb1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndata.Click


        Dim total As Double = 0.0
    Using reader As New StreamReader("c://temp/DailyApr12log.csv")
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(",".ToCharArray())
            total += Double.Parse(fields(7))
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
    End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim files() As String
    files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp", "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each FileName As String In files
        cmb1.Items.Add(FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1, FileName.Length - FileName.LastIndexOf("\") - 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Any ideas on how to output the averages of a .csv in Visual Basic?

Comment: are you getting files always in same format, columns ?

Comment: Where is your CSV parsing code here? Can't see it.

Comment: Tip: [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) makes working with file paths much easier.

Comment: each line on the file goes like this:10/04/2012,00:00,6.439582,79.71528,3.138889,8.868753,33,264.8125
11/04/2012,00:00,7.853473,76.41666,3.701389,7.065973,33,277.4722
12/04/2012,00:00,7.622221,64.99306,0.9236111,6.268749,33,214.9861
13/04/2012,00:00,7.24236,66.82639,1.319444,6.898612,33,136.8472
14/04/2012,00:00,6.952778,55.40278,-1.548611,10.11389,33,109.5764
15/04/2012,00:00,6.285417,56.97222,-2.243056,6.869443,33,137.4861
16/04/2012,00:00,7.205556,67.625,1.3125,8.19236,33,149.9514

Comment: I have updated the code I can read the .csv but not sure how to output the data i need correctly